# chkdsk log file location on windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, chkdsk

Where can I find the log file of the **chkdsk** utility that runs when the server starts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Start the Event Viewer.
2. Navigate to Windows Logs -> Application.
3. Look for entries with Source=Wininit, Event ID=1001.

Answer (score 2):

I would search for bootex.log.  It may in the root of the system drive (where \windows sits) - normally c:.

Comment: on Win2008r2, i do not see that file even though i know chkdsk ran, but i have seen it before on other machines.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it puts it in event viewer.